# Does anyone know of potential problems with st_line_substring in postGIS?

Tags: postgis

Specifically I'm getting a result that I do not understand. It is possible that my understanding is simply wrong, but I don't think so. So I'm hoping that someone will either say "yes, that's a known problem" or "no, it is working correct and here is why your understanding is wrong".

Here is my example.

To start I have the following geometry of lat/longs.

> LINESTRING(-1.32007599 51.06707497,-1.31192207 51.09430508,-1.30926132 51.10206677,-1.30376816 51.11133597,-1.29261017 51.12981493,-1.27510071 51.15906713,-1.27057314 51.16440941,-1.26606703 51.16897072,-1.26235485 51.17439257,-1.26089573 51.17875111,-1.26044512 51.1833917,-1.25793457 51.19727033,-1.25669003 51.20141159,-1.25347137 51.20630532,-1.24845028 51.21110444,-1.23325825 51.22457158,-1.2274003 51.22821321,-1.22038364 51.23103494,-1.20326042 51.23596583,-1.1776185 51.24346193,-1.16356373 51.24968088,-1.13167763 51.26363353,-1.12247229 51.2659966,-1.11629248 51.26682901,-1.10906124 51.26728549,-1.09052181 51.26823871,-1.08522177 51.26885628,-1.07013702 51.27070895,-1.03683472 51.27350122,-1.00917578 51.27572955,-0.98243952 51.2779175,-0.9509182 51.28095094,-0.9267354 51.28305811,-0.90499878 51.28511151,-0.86051702 51.2883055,-0.83661318 51.29023789,-0.7534647 51.29708113,-0.74908733 51.29795323,-0.7400322 51.2988924,-0.71535587 51.30125366,-0.68475723 51.29863749,-0.65746307 51.30220618,-0.63246489 51.30380261,-0.60542822 51.30645873,-0.58150291 51.3103219,-0.57603121 51.31150225,-0.57062387 51.31317883,-0.54195642 51.32475227,-0.4855442 51.34771616,-0.4553318 51.36283147)

This is in a column called "geom" in my table, called "fibre_lines". When I run the following query,

```
select st_length(geography(geom), false) as full_length,
  st_length(geography(st_line_substring(geom, 0, 1)), false) as full_length_2,
  st_length(geography(st_line_substring(geom, 0, 0.5)), false) as first_half,
  st_length(geography(st_line_substring(geom, 0.5, 1)), false) as second_half
from fibre_lines
where id = 10;
```

I get the following result...

> 76399.4939375278   76399.4939375278    41008.9667229201    35390.5272197668

The first two make sense to me, they are simply the length of my line assuming a spherical earth. The first is just using the obvious function while the second is using st_line_substring to get the length of the entire line. These two values agree.

But the last two have me puzzled. I am asking for the length of the first half of the line, then I'm asking for the length of the last half. My expectation was that these would be equal or nearly equal. Instead the first half is about 6km longer than the second half.

If you plot the geometry on the map you will see that the first third of the line is fairly north/south oriented and the remaining two thirds are more east/west. I wouldn't have thought that would make a difference when asking for the length on a spherical earth, but I am happy to be told that I'm wrong (so long as it is also explained why I'm wrong).

For reference the `PostGIS` I am using is *1.5.8.* If this is a bug, upgrading to a newer version is possible, but not trivial, so I would prefer to only do that if it is necessary.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Do ST_AsText(ST_Line_SubString(geom, 0, 0.5))
and
ST_AsText(ST_Line_SubString(geom, .5, 1))

have matching end and start points?

Comment: This question seems to suggest that you probably don't want to use st_length:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63762/why-is-sum-of-st-length-of-segments-20-too-big

Answer (score 0):

While Arunas' comments didn't directly answer my question, it did lead me to some research that I think identifies the problem. I'm posting it here in part to get it straight in my own mind and in part in case others are wondering.

It seems the key is the PostGIS distinction between a "geometry" and a "geography". A geometry is a 2D planar geometry that is typically in UTMs and used with a projection of the globe onto a flat surface (which projection is configurable). A geography, on the other hand, is designed to store latitude/longitude information specifically and is used to work either on a sphere or a spheroid. So the essential problem I have is twofold:

1. Perhaps not obvious from my original post is that I am using a geometry object to store lat/long information rather than UTMs. I cast that to a geography most of the time so that I get the correct answers, but it would be more correct if I actually stored it as a geography object. That would eliminate the need for a number of the casts in my code as well as allow PostGIS to tell me when I am doing something wrong.
2. While ST_Length will work with either a geometry or a geography, ST_Line_Substring only works with geometries. Hence when I ask it for the halfway point, I am asking it for the halfway point of a flat geometry. This will give me the correct answer for the latitude coordinate, but for the longitude it will have an error term that increases (for most projections) the farther I am from the equator.

I've looked into newer versions of PostGIS and they don't seem to have an ST_Line_Substring or anything similar that will give me the 50% point of a geography, so I will have to do it the "hard" way by using ST_Length to give me all my segment lengths and then adding them up and doing the math needed for my interpolation.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't add comments so will provide it as an answer.

I experienced the same problem and I resolved by transforming my lat-lon geometries to utm geometries into st_line_substring function call. The I as getting sub-geometries with proper length. Of course I had to transform them back to lat-lon afterward.